# Getting value from a key type TimeUUID in Cassandra-PHP

Tags: php, cassandra, phpcassa

I'm new in cassandra and I wanna get the values from a column family, where the key is a TimeUUIDType.

I'm using PHP with PHPCassa, and I can insert(set) correctly in the column family, generating uuid with the function:

```
$key = CassandraUtil::uuid1();
```

The problem happen when I try to do a get in the column family, because i have and uuid in String format( something like that):

```
$uuidString= "e2658820-69f2-11e1-af9a-95dd4f324d9";
```

I would like to know if is possible cast or transform an String form to a valid uuid for cassandra in php or phpcassa, because my purpose is in another page create the correct uuid from the $uuuidString.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CassandraUtil::import($uuidString)` will handle that.

**Edit**
As of phpcassa 1.0+, `\phpcassa\UUID::import()` is the proper method.

Comment: @user815672 you're welcome! If this works for you, don't forget to accept the answer so that others can know the question has been solved.