# Converting timeuuid to date-time in phpcassa

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa, timeuuid

I'm trying to get date from timeuuid without calling `dateOf(id)` function in cqlsh.
So, is there any function in phpcassa that can convert timeuuid to date ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638198/getting-value-from-a-key-type-timeuuid-in-cassandra-php

Comment: Well, in the latest version, there's no `CassandraUtil` but there exist `UUID::import($timeuuid)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$time` attribute of `\phpcassa\UUID` objects to get a unix timestamp, like so:

```
$timeuuid = UUID::uuid1();
echo "timestamp: $timeuuid->time";
```

From there it's easy to make other date and time objects.

Comment: Well, I try to convert an existing string timeuuid to `uuid1`. i.e `$timeuuid = "0e6f9df0-fb40-11e2-8bbc-ef32f0e43a97"`. I'm trying to get timestamp out of it. How can I do that ?

Comment: You need to create a UUID object from that string first by doing `$timeuuid = UUID::import("0e6f9df0-fb40-11e2-8bbc-ef32f0e43a97");`